# Is it possible to customize the Okta Sign-In Widget with Angular Material components?

Tags: angular, angular-material, okta

I’ve just added [@okta/okta-signin-widget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-signin-widget) to my Angular SPA, and it renders something like:

```html
<span>
    <input id="okta-signin-username" type="text">
</span>
```

I style my Angular SPA using the Angular Material library , which requires a different DOM structure:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input id="okta-signin-username" type="text" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Because of Angular’s component factories, I can’t simply re-structure the DOM with javascript like below:

```js
this.widget.on('ready', (context) => {
    // This WON'T work!
    const username = document.getElementById('okta-signin-username');
    const field = document.createElement('mat-form-field');
    const parent = username.parentElement;
    field.appendChild(username);
    parent.appendChild(field);
});
```

Sure, this’ll change the DOM, but this circumvents Angular’s component factories, which are necessary for producing the complete structure:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ...">
          <div class="mat-form-field-flex ...">
              <div class="mat-form-field-infix ...">
                  <input id="okta-signin-username" type="text" matInput>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I’m currently playing around with Angular’s ComponentFactorResolver as mentioned in https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader. I think I’ll be trying to combine the above javascript with the use of a component factory - but maybe the widget will have issues if I try that? Maybe there’s an easier way?

Could I perhaps create my own sign-in form and move the inputs from the widget into it once rendered?

Thanks for any hints and help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be: use the [@okta/okta-auth-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-auth-js) library instead.

For additional help using [@okta/okta-auth-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-auth-js), see [this Okta tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/01/21/angular-material-login).

Credit to [mraible](https://devforum.okta.com/t/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-okta-sign-in-widget-with-angular-material-components/12324) from the Okta team for this solution.